# split a string and get the first two sections (if they exist) in python

Tags: python

I have these strings in Python:

```
a=['One','one_two','one_two_three','one_two_three_four']
```

And I need to get the two first parts (splitting based on '_').

I can write something like this:

```
for c in a:
    
    x=c.split("_", 2)
    if(len(x)>=2):
        y=x[0]+'_'+x[1]
    else:
        y=x[0]
    print(y)
```

But is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could improve the `if` by just getting the first 2 (`[:2]`) from the `split()` and then `join()` them back together:

```py
a=['One','one_two','one_two_three','one_two_three_four']

for c in a:
    
    x=c.split("_")[:2]
    y='_'.join(x)
    print(y)

# One-liner variant
# [ print('_'.join(c.split("_")[:2])) for c in a ]
```

```
One
one_two
one_two
one_two
```

##### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5NCsMgEIX3nmJIFyq0WbS7gGfoAYKIBEMsYRQ7bePprUhpILN4zPuYnxczLQFvpVg18js6fuYBnaFP2DtDS3Lu6M0cXolrxuaQYAKPYAcGtZpsauqfcfUkOtPJcbjqhrPihveP4FFsspGYPJLIkrET1P@X1aNL8LbJW6TKxt/Ef@94V0rYE4Au5Qs)

Comment: You don't need the second argument to *split()*

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this by using the *sep* argument to *print()* as follows:

```
a = ['One', 'one_two', 'one_two_three', 'one_two_three_four']

for c in a:
    print(*c.split('_')[:2], sep='_')
```

**Output:**

```
One
one_two
one_two
one_two
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a way that uses [`find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) and doesn't rely on `split()`, which will be more efficient since the pieces get joined again in a way that reverses the effect of `split()`:

```py
for c in a:
    i = c.find('_')
    if i != -1:
        i = c.find('_', i + 1)
    y = c if i == -1 else c[:i]
    print(y)
```

Output:

```
One
one_two
one_two
one_two
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a one-liner using a list comprehension:

```
['_'.join(c.split('_')[:2]) for c in a]
```

It splits the string with respect to '_', takes at most 2 segments and joins them back, placing a '_' in between.
Keep in mind that this returns a processed list, so you would still need to print it out.